# Android transition not working on phone

Tags: android, transition

I created some transitions between activities that are working fine in the emulator, but nothing of them can be seen on the phone (neither fade in-out nor slide). The new activity simply appears like I have not implemented any transitions. Why is that?

fadein.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
   android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="1000" />
```

fadeout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="1000" />
```

And i set in the appropriate activity

```
 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure that animations are enabled on device. For this go to Settings->Display->Animations and select "All Animations".

Comment: Wow. After googling for 2 hours I didn't find anything that mentioned that. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Enable the transition animation

Settings -> Developer Options -> Transition Animation Scale -> 1x

Comment: 5 years later and this advice is still solid.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settigs then developer options and check for the options that are related to animation and assure that each one of animation option is switched on